# Certificate migration from Letsencrypt to AWS certificate manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, aws-certificate-manager

I have a domain called `abc.xyz.com` for which I have installed `letsencrypt` on that (apache for web serving) Ubuntu 16.04 as OS and added `A record` set in `Route53` for some time - a year. Now the same thing AWS has launched called as `AWS Certificate Manager`.

Problem Statement:

I have created a wildcard certificate as `*.xyz.com` in AWS Certificate 
 Manager and created a CNAME entry  `abc.xyz.com` in AWS Route53 and using `*.xyz.com` as my certificate name in the Elastic Load Balancer with 2 instances.

The Problem is the request is routing back to old instance `(A record)` with the letsencrypt certificate. We have also checked with many tools like `dnschecker.org` as well `dig/nslookup` command but found no look.

Please help us out.